Playwright using cucumber not taking screenshots When using FAILED STATUS
Hey i facing an issue regarding taking screenshots and added to the cucumber-html reporter using playwright
And for me is a weird issue
So if i add status.PASSED it works is taking screenshots and also add video to report
The issue cames when i want to add only screenshots and videos on Status.FAILED
The report is generated but no screnshots are taken and no video attachment to the report
Hooks.ts
After(async function ({ pickle, result }) {
  let videoPath: string;
  let img: Buffer;
  const path = `./test-result/trace/${pickle.id}.zip`;
  if (result?.status == Status.FAILED) {
    console.log("Test failed, taking screenshot and video...");
    img = await pageFixture.page.screenshot({
      path: `./test-result/screenshots/${pickle.name}.png`,
      type: "png",
    });
    videoPath = await pageFixture.page.video().path();
  }
  await context.tracing.stop({ path: path });
  // await pageFixture.page.close();
  // await context.close();
  if (result?.status == Status.FAILED) {
    await this.attach(img, "image/png");
    await this.attach(fs.readFileSync(videoPath), "video/webm");
    const traceFileLink = `<a href="https://trace.playwright.dev/">Open ${path}</a>`;
    await this.attach(`Trace file: ${traceFileLink}`, "text/html");
  }
  // Close the page and context after all operations are done
  await pageFixture.page.close();
  await context.close();
});

package.json
 "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npx ts-node src/helper/report/init.ts",
    "test": "cross-env ENV=stage cucumber-js --config=config/cucumber.js test || echo \"Test failed\"",
    "posttest": "npx ts-node src/helper/report/reporter.ts",
    "test:failed": "cross-env ENV=stage cucumber-js @rerun.txt --format rerun:@rerun.txt"
  },

cucumber.js
module.exports = {
  default: {
    tags: process.env.npm_config_TAGS || "",
    formatOptions: {
      snippetInterface: "async-await",
    },
    paths: ["src/test/features/"],
    dryRun: false,
    require: ["src/test/steps/*.ts", "src/hooks/hooks.ts"],
    requireModule: ["ts-node/register"],
    format: [
      "progress-bar",
      "html:test-result/cucumber-report.html",
      "json:test-result/cucumber-report.json",
      "rerun:@rerun.txt",
    ],
    parallel: 0,
  },
  rerun: {
    formatOptions: {
      snippetInterface: "async-await",
    },
    dryRun: false,
    require: ["src/test/steps/*.ts", "src/hooks/hooks.ts"],
    requireModule: ["ts-node/register"],
    format: [
      "progress-bar",
      "html:test-result/cucumber-report.html",
      "json:test-result/cucumber-report.json",
      "rerun:@rerun.txt",
    ],
    parallel: 0,
  },
};


When i change the status to PASSED the test take screen shots and passed in to the report
if (result?.status == Status.PASSED) {
    console.log("Test failed, taking screenshot and video...");
    img = await pageFixture.page.screenshot({
      path: `./test-result/screenshots/${pickle.name}.png`,
      type: "png",
    });
    videoPath = await pageFixture.page.video().path();
  }
  await context.tracing.stop({ path: path });
  // await pageFixture.page.close();
  // await context.close();
  if (result?.status == Status.PASSED) {
    await this.attach(img, "image/png");
    await this.attach(fs.readFileSync(videoPath), "video/webm");
    const traceFileLink = `<a href="https://trace.playwright.dev/">Open ${path}</a>`;
    await this.attach(`Trace file: ${traceFileLink}`, "text/html");
  }


Can you check the value in result?.status in After function when scenario gets failed?
